# Add/remove UILocalNotification based on changes in my settings bundle

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, settings.bundle

I have an app that sends a notification at the same time everyday, reminding the user to enter data into it. However, I want to give the user teh option to disable this as this could get very annoying, so I have an "Enable alerts" in a custom settings bundle. My question is, when the user toggles the switch in the settings bundle, can I add/remove the notifications that are already scheduled without having to enter the app again?

note: I'm building and supporting for iOS 4.2.1, and I don't konw why but under "notifications" in the settings app, my app does not appear. I see it on ios 5.x devices though

Comment: No, those effects won't take affect until you run the app again. Probably better to have that setting **in** the app to insure the results you want.